# Changing a resource at runtime?

Tags: delphi, resources, runtime

I have the following problem: I need to create two exe in Delphi. One of them will contain a resource and zip format, we call it primeiro.exe, the other will only have the function to change this within the first resource and we will call it segundo.exe.

When I run segundo.exe and it will change the resource that is within primeiro.exe, add files in the zip, remove, etc.. How to do this?

Replacing the whole zip folder by another also solves my problem!

Comment: Not sure what your exact problem is, but you might want to have a look at [UpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Are you asking how to change a resource inside an EXE that has already been compiled?   Or are you asking how to change the resource file, so that the next time the EXE is built, the compiler will use the new resource.

Comment: Inside an exe that has already been compiled.

Comment: If people keep asking for information in comments, it's a sign that your question is poorly written or unclear, and the best thing to do at that point is to [edit] the question itself to improve it. Please do so instead of just posting things in comments. The question is unclear, and you've been given a link that has information that might help - have you looked at the information in that link, or searched for information on UpdateResosurce and Delphi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API for modifying linked resources is accessed with `BeginUpdateResource`, `UpdateResource` and `EndUpdateResource`. Consult the API documentation on MSDN to learn how to use these functions, and also refer to the [example code on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648008.aspx#_win32_Updating_Resources).

Including large ZIP file resources in an executable, and frequently modifying them, seems to me like the sort of behaviour that would attract attention from anti-malware software. Don't be too surprised if this causes problems.